# What enterprise sites are using ASP.NET MVC / MVC 2? Need justification for management for moving to MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I've tried a few google searches and stack over flow searches, but this is proving hard to find than I thought. I need to provide justification to management for our shop to move to ASP.NET MVC 2. The biggest help would be any enterprise level sites or major web development shops that are using ASP.NET MVC 1/2.

Does anyone have a list or link?

I know Stackoverflow uses it, but some stats such as daily views would help too. I found the Jwaala case study here: http://www.microsoft.com/casestudies/case_study_detail.aspx?casestudyid=4000006675 . Aside from that, I'm having some issues finding some professional examples.

Thanks in advance!

Just found a few more case studies:

http://www.microsoft.com/casestudies/Case_Study_Search_Results.aspx?Type=1&Keywords=mvc&LangID=46#top

Could still use more links.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your management requires a "...but THEY're doing it!!!" justification then you have larger problems.

If you're using the "...but THEY're doing it!!!" justification then you'll likely need much better reasons.

---

Hate to troll, but just saying that you'll want objective and project-specific reasoning.  And if by "management" you mean business-management, then they need to understand that engineering details are best left up to engineering.  The Art of War by Sun Tzu is full of advice along these lines.

...and to qualify this, I'm a web-developer working on a partial rewrite of a WebForms app.  I'd love to be using MVC for this project, but the actual benefit of doing so doesn't match the cost--business is business after all, and the business-case must be considered.

If you do get stuck with WebForms then you can whip it into shape (what we're doing).  With ASP.NET 4.0 (or a little inheritance trickery) you can get rid of the ID renaming; by building ViewModels, domain-objects, and clean Repositories you can avoid a lot of the cruft of WebForms--we have tight, explicit control over what WebForms generates.  We've shrunk the actual content of our ASPX pages and their codebehinds by at least an order of magnitude by applying best practices.

Just remember, the tools won't make you a better developer, and unless you know what you're doing or what you're working with then you won't reap the benefits.

Comment: Thanks for your response and I definitely see what you mean. I actually do think the move is in our companies best interest as I'm the only .Net developer on a team of 5 and I really think MVC is more intuitive. That leads to the rest of the team picking it up more quickly, and projects getting completed sooner than they would otherwise. Still, management does want reassurance that this framework isn't some kind of programming fling or Microsoft experiment. Unfortunately, the whole '...but THEY're doing it!!!' works for them. A few big name sites and stats will go a long way.

Answer (score 3):

**Dell** is rebuilding its page from ASP.NET Webforms into ASP.NET MVC as Phil Haack is mentioned this on his [blog](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/02/28/austin-texas-great-for-geeks.aspx) ;)

I can not say if they use MVC 1 or MVC 2.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that MarketWatch use ASP.NET MVC with Spark View Engine as listed here :
http://sparkviewengine.com/spark-in-the-field
http://www.marketwatch.com/

also an e-commerce webiste :

http://www.fancydressoutfitters.co.uk/

Answer (score 0):

Check our sites [www.reifen.com](http://www.reifen.com) and [www.bonspneus.fr](http://www.bonspneus.fr). They handle pretty big traffic in germany and france.

We have used ASP.NET MVC 1 on these sites and still use (and enjoy) ASP.NET on other sites. Like others said: don't just go with ASP.NET MVC because it is in some way better.  It is not. There is allways a situation where I would prefer one or the other.

Answer (score 0):

Additional "live" ASP.NET MVC sites (some broken links)

http://weblogs.asp.net/mikebosch/archive/2008/05/05/gallery-of-live-asp-net-mvc-sites.aspx